# Tutorials/WritingServiceClient

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, begginer-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am working through the beginner tutorials and have been trying everything to get the beginner_tutorials node to make. It keeps failing at the set target properties command of my cmakelist. I have reproduced it below, I also have put in my .bashrc (last three/four lines) I'm running on the Windows sublayer (ubuntu) if that matters. Any help is appreciated.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)  
project(beginner_tutorials)  
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS  
  roscpp  
  rospy  
  std_msgs  
  message_generation  
)  

 add_message_files(  
   FILES  
   Num.msg  
 )  

 add_service_files(  
   FILES  
   AddTwoInts.srv  
 )  
 generate_messages(  
   DEPENDENCIES  
   std_msgs  
 )  
catkin_package(  
 # INCLUDE_DIRS include  
 # LIBRARIES beginner_tutorials  
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_runtime  
 # DEPENDS system_lib  
)  
include_directories(  
# include  
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}  
)  
 set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_node PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME node PREFIX "")
```

.bashrc

```
export DISPLAY=:0  
EDITOR='nano -w'  
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash  
source devel/setup.bash  
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287572/tutorials/writingserviceclient/) by [DeltaWaldo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34503/deltawaldo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-04-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-05**:
You'll need to include an error message or a description of what doesn't work, because we can't guess these things ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears that you are missing the `add_executable` line in your CMakeLists.txt to define the target name and the sources to use when compiling that target. Without knowing exactly which tutorial you're following (please provide a link), I'm not sure what the right thing to put there is.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1